# How can i add screenshot to allure-cucumber report with ruby?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, allure

would you kindly help me is there any work to provide support for attaching add screenshot to allure-cucumber report.
I using this construction

```
After do |scenario|
  @browser.save_screenshot if scenario.failed?
  include AllureCucumber::DSL
  attach_file("07Apr2017114056.png",File.open("../../src/screen/07Apr2017114056.png"))
  @browser.quit
end
```

but it dont work and give me erorr msg:
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ../../src/screen/07Apr2017114056.png
What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

it is will wor only with this comand  --format AllureCucumber::Formatter --out

Answer (score 0):

file = save_screenshot("images/#{name}.png")

Allure.add_attachment(name: 'Screenshot', source: File.open(file, 'rb'), type: Allure::ContentType::PNG, test_case: true)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).